# gzip compression and leverage browser caching in htaccess is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, gzip

**PHP Version 5.3.29**

SERVER_SOFTWARE: Apache/2

HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip

gzip compression: enabled

here is the link: [PHPINFO](http://bakemate.in/phpinfo.php)

---

Here is the code of compression and leverage browser caching -

---

`<IfModule mod_deflate.c>`

```
`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml`

`AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/javascript`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain`

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml`
```

`</IfModule>`

### EXPIRES CACHING

`<IfModule mod_headers.c>`

`<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|woff|js|css)$">`

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
```

`</FilesMatch>`

`</IfModule>`

I checked in everywhere. but no code is working. Please anyone suggests what should I do. I'm using WordPress. I don't want to use unnecessary plugins. Is it a php version issue?

Project link: [Link](http://bakemate.in/)

Comment: Your phpinfo link response encoding is gzip . Doesn't that mean it works?

Comment: I don't know what is the issue. the htaccess file is the correct file. But the code is not working.

Comment: Are you sure your host/server support gzip? sometimes phpinfo say enabled but they blocked this service for you, If you using shared host

Comment: @Pedram phpinfo() shows that. I did not talk to them

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Comment: compression and browser caching are not working. I have code in htaccess file but it's not working @apokryfos

Comment: @Satyaki compression is working for the phpinfo page. Any specific link that's not working as expected?

Comment: I have given the link because you guys see the phpinfo. If there is any problem in the server configuration or not. My project link is: http://bakemate.in/

Comment: Your config seems to work but you're not including gif jpeg or png images in the output filters. The other content types seem to be gzip and most things do have the cache control header. You should find each offending resource and verify that there's no overriding .htaccess in its directory

Comment: The directives you have there are wrapped in `IfModule` explicitly so that they won’t cause an error if the modules providing them are not available. Either check with your hoster, whether they are, or remove those and see if you get an error without them.

Comment: @apokryfos I know that but css and js files should work. It's not working though. Here is the link of google page speed : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbakemate.in%2F&tab=desktop

Comment: @CBroe I did not get you properly. Should I write my code without <ifmodule> ?

Comment: That would be one way to find out whether those modules are enabled and you are allowed to specify those settings (because otherwise that would result in a 500 Internal Server Error.)

Comment: odd thing is that the linked page says that https://pasteboard.co/H7hfrAQ.png is not zipped . Do you have any sort of user agent filter or something?

Comment: @CBroe I did that but It's running fine without <ifmodule>.

Comment: @apokryfos I did not get you properly.

Comment: I am receiving `bootstrap.min.css` in a gzip compressed format with the correct cache max age. The pagespeed insights page says that this file needs to have compression enabled. This means that for some reason apache does correctly gzip the file to my browser but does not compress it when requested by the google insights crawler.

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing that too. It seems to some server issue.